# Ramification index of infinite primes

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I am reading Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory. On page 184, Chapter 3, Neukirch defines the ramification index of infinite primes as follows:
For a finite extension $L/K$ of number fields, and an infinite prime $\mathfrak{B}$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$, define the inertia degree resp. ramification index by $e_{\mathfrak{B}/\mathfrak{p}}=1$.

But I am confused: in the case where $\mathfrak{p}$ comes from a real embedding $\sigma$, and $\mathfrak{B}$ comes from a complex (non-real) embedding $\tau$ extending $\sigma$, don't we say $\mathfrak{p}$ ramifies in $L$, because both $\tau$ and $\bar{\tau}$ extend $\sigma$?

Thanks.

**Add:** Neukirch also defines $f_{\mathfrak{B}/\mathfrak{p}}=[L_\mathfrak{B}:K_\mathfrak{p}]$ (loc. cit.) but I think the natural definitions analogues to finite cases should be $f_{\mathfrak{B}/\mathfrak{p}}=\log|\tau(x)|/\log|\sigma(x)|$ for some $x\in K_\mathfrak{p}^\times$, which always equals 1 for $\tau$ extending $\sigma$. It seems Neukirch is using a non-standard convention here? If so is it good for something?

Comment: I think this convention is chosen if you want to have a result like his Proposition 1.2.(i) be true for arbitrary primes, including the infinite primes... Unless you allow e=2 when going from the reals to the complex numbers, but then say f=1 in this case.

Comment: Prop 1.2(i) is easily salvaged by saying f=1 and e=2 for complex embeddings extending real ones, but (iii) and (iv) seem to me to require his convention...